# How to read a text file where some of the contents have line breaks?

Tags: python

I have a text file of this form:

```
06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde

fghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde

fghe

ijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde
```

You can see that every line is separated by a line break, but some row contents have line breaks in them.  So, simply separating by line doesn't parse every line properly.

As an example, for the 5th entry, I want my output to be
    `07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde fghe`

Here is my current code:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as text_file:
data = []
for line in text_file:
    row = line.strip()
    data.append(row)
```

Comment: Is the data that can contain line breaks itself contained in double-quotes, by any chance?

Comment: Could you show how `data` should look? It is unclear from your description. I see income, but it is not clear how outcome should look.

Comment: I want each element of `data` to start with a date.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes it is

Comment: @Imran then you probably have some type of CSV. If you know what the separator is, you could do this trivially using the `csv` module. Can you post the first few rows of the data?

Comment: @Imran, you mean you want to remove `fghe` and `ijkl` and just keep elements like this `06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde`?

Comment: @TitanFighter No, `"abcde\n\nfghe\n\nijkl"` are all part of the data.

Comment: @TitanFighter no I want it all in a single element - it's part of the contents.

Comment: Are the linebreaks in the data identical to the ones that separate the actual data lines?

Comment: @handle I'm fairly sure they are.

Comment: @Imran can you post a few rows of the actual data? It is almost certainly some sort of csv, in which case, the right answer is to simply use the `csv` module and not write your own parser.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the actual data is the same as what I posted but with more text and more rows.

Comment: But as you said it has *doube quotes*, right? Where are the double quotes, and more importantly **what is the delimiter**?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga here's a sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/leuvfsnu6y98v00/test.txt?dl=0

Comment: Ok, so there are no quotes. Never mind then.

Comment: You could try parsing the first item in each line with [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and see if it raises a `ValueError` or not (i.e. via `try`/`except`). If it doesn't, you can assume it's part of the previous line.

Comment: @ Imran If possible, you need to sanitize user input and delimit the data field. Otherwise data sets cannot be separated reliably.

Comment: Pretty much all you need is to replace `\n\n` for a white space: `'\n'.join(data).replace('\n\n', ' ').split('\n'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example input, you can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jHRkBW/1/) with a forward lookahead:

```
pat=re.compile(r'^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d.*?)(?=^^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d|\Z)', re.S | re.M)

with open (fn) as f:
    pprint([m.group(1) for m in pat.finditer(f.read())])
```

Prints:

```
['06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde\n\nfghe\n',
 '07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde\n\nfghe\n\nijkl\n',
 '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde\n']
```

---

With the Dropbox example, prints:

```
['11/11/2015, 3:16 pm - IK: 12\n',
 '13/11/2015, 12:10 pm - IK: Hi.\n\nBut this is not about me.\n\nA donation, however small, will go a long way.\n\nThank you.\n',
 '13/11/2015, 12:11 pm - IK: Boo\n',
 '15/11/2015, 8:36 pm - IR: Root\n',
 '15/11/2015, 8:36 pm - IR: LaTeX?\n',
 '15/11/2015, 8:43 pm - IK: Ws\n']
```

If you want to delete the `\n` in what is captured, just add `m.group(1).strip().replace('\n', '')` to the list comprehension above.

---

Explanation of regex:

```
^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d.*?)(?=^^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d|\Z)

^                                                       start of line   
    ^  ^  ^  ^   ^                                      pattern for a date  
                       ^                                capture the rest...  
                           ^                            until (look ahead)
                                      ^ ^ ^             another date
                                                  ^     or
                                                     ^  end of string
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!  Can you explain what the code inside `re.compile` does?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `','` can only appear as a separator, we may check if the line has a comma and concatenate it to the last row if it doesn't:

```
data = []

with open('file.txt', 'r') as text_file:
    for line in text_file:
        row = line.strip()
        if ',' not in row:
            data[-1] += '\n' + row
        else:
            data.append(row)
```

Comment: Nothing so far is preventing a comma from appearing in the data (actually, in the data file linked in the question's comments, there are several). Reliable separation is not possible.

Comment: When I posted there was only the example in the question and my code would be "the simplest thing that could possibly work". But with the data linked in the comments you are right, it wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions (using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module) to check for dates like this:

```
import re
with open('file.txt', 'r') as text_file:
  data = []
  for line in text_file:
    row = line.strip()
    if re.match(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*'):  
      data.append(row)  # date: new record
    else:
      data[-1] += '\n' + row  # no date: append to last record

# '\d{2}': two digits
# '.*': any character, zero or more times
```

Comment: Like any other approach so far: breaks if data contains the delimiter sequence (a date in this format).

Answer (score 0):

Simple testing for length:

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8

data = """06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde

fghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde

fghe

ijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde"""

lines = data.split("\n")
out = []
for l in lines:
    c = l.strip()
    if c:
        if len(c) < 10:
            out[-1] += c
        else:
            out.append(c)
    #skip empty

for o in out:
    print(o)
```

results in:

```
06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcdefghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcdefgheijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde
```

*Does not contain the line breaks in the data!*

---

But this one liner regular expression should do it (split on linebreak followed by digit), at least for the sample data (breaks when data contains linebreak followed by digit):

```
#!python3
#coding=utf-8

text_file = """06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde

fghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde

fghe

ijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde"""

import re
data = re.split("\n(?=\d)", text_file)

print(data)

for d in data:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
   ['06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde', '07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde', '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde', '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde', '07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde\n\
nfghe', '07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde', '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde\n\nfghe\n\nijkl', '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde']
06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde

fghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde

fghe

ijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde
```

---

(fixed with lookahead)

Comment: Fails if data contains linebreak+digit, so the regular expression needs to be extended. On the other hand, this method [without sanitizing data, no delimiters] is easily broken if the data contains a new line with something that looks like a data header...

Comment: What if one of the dates is `12/21/2016`? If you use `re.split(r'\n\d', txt)` your date becomes `2/21/2016`...

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that it consumes the digit.

Comment: You can fix that with a look ahead -- like this solution I posted: `re.split(r'\n(?=^\d)', txt)`

Comment: Didn't know about `\Z`yet, thanks. [Ok you've removed it again..]

Comment: `\Z` is actually not needed with `split` since the last element is included anyway. It is useful for a similar solution using `findall` or `finditer` that would not include the final element with out the look ahead seeing the end of string.