# Did something change in the encoding of Whatsapp chat exports?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to follow a tutorial/example on how to import Whatsapp chat text exports into a Pandas dataframe, found [here](https://imrankhan17.github.io/pages/Exploring%20WhatsApp%20chats%20with%20Python.html).

When I tried to run it, there was an encoding issue (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1123: character maps to <undefined>`) and a type error (`TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator` that I addressed using [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45388800/python-data-argument-cant-be-an-iterator?rq=1)).

However, for some reason, when I pass in the file exported from Whatsapp with `encoding='utf8'` (I tried other options but the file is UTF-8), it just produces an empty dataframe.

When it didn't work, I found the Stack Overflow post the author created to get their code, which is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835320/how-to-read-a-text-file-where-some-of-the-contents-have-line-breaks). But it seems to work seamlessly and doesn't have any errors.

This is the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse_file(text_file):
    '''Convert WhatsApp chat log text file to a Pandas dataframe.'''

    # some regex to account for messages taking up multiple lines
    pat = re.compile(r'^(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d.*?)(?=^^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d|\Z)', re.S | re.M)
    with open(text_file) as f:
        data = [m.group(1).strip().replace('\n', ' ') for m in pat.finditer(f.read())]

    sender = []; message = []; datetime = []
    for row in data:

        # timestamp is before the first dash
        datetime.append(row.split(' - ')[0])

        # sender is between am/pm, dash and colon
        try:
            s = re.search('m - (.*?):', row).group(1)
            sender.append(s)
        except:
            sender.append('')

        # message content is after the first colon
        try:
            message.append(row.split(': ', 1)[1])
        except:
            message.append('')

    df = pd.DataFrame(zip(datetime, sender, message), columns=['timestamp', 'sender', 'message'])
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%d/%m/%Y, %I:%M %p')

    # remove events not associated with a sender
    df = df[df.sender != ''].reset_index(drop=True)

    return df

df = parse_file('chat_data_anon.txt')
```

My expected results are the same as the author described in their SO post:

I have this:

```
06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde

fghe
07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde

fghe

ijkl
07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde
```

and want:

```
['06/01/2016, 10:40 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:04 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 12:05 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 6:14 pm - abcde\n\nfghe\n',
 '07/01/2016, 6:20 pm - abcde\n',
 '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde\n\nfghe\n\nijkl\n',
 '07/01/2016, 7:58 pm - abcde\n']
```

... Except I only get an empty dataframe. When I broke it into pieces, it seems `data` is empty. The file I passed is exactly how Whatsapp exported it (a simple .txt file), with no changes.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Will replacing ```return df``` with ```return df.tolist()``` do the trick for you?

Answer (score 0):

My friend, what i did and worked for me was first read my .txt file... example:

opened_file = open("file.txt", encoding="utf8").read()

therefore you can work with opened_file .

Answer (score 0):

I made 3 small changes and the code is now working well for me:

1- The format of the dates don't always have two digits for days and months, but it always has two digits for years. I adjusted the regex to reflect it:

r'^(\d+/\d+/\d\d.*?)(?=^^\d+/\d+/\d\d,*?)'

2- The end of the datatime field has either AM or PM in capital letters:

s = re.search('M - (.*?):', row).group(1)

3 - The datetime format is actually month/day/year:

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def parse_file(FULL_PATH):
    '''Convert WhatsApp chat log text file to a Pandas dataframe.'''

    # some regex to account for messages taking up multiple lines
    pat = re.compile(r'^(\d+\/\d+\/\d\d.*?)(?=^^\d+\/\d+\/\d\d\,\*?)', re.S | re.M)
    with open(FULL_PATH, encoding = 'utf8') as raw:
        data = [m.group(1).strip().replace('\n', ' ') for m in pat.finditer(raw.read())]
    
    sender = []; message = []; datetime = []
    for row in data:

        # timestamp is before the first dash
        datetime.append(row.split(' - ')[0])

        # sender is between am/pm, dash and colon
        try:
            s = re.search('M - (.*?):', row).group(1)
            sender.append(s)
        except:
            sender.append('')

        # message content is after the first colon
        try:
            message.append(row.split(': ', 1)[1])
        except:
            message.append('')

    df = pd.DataFrame(zip(datetime, sender, message), columns=['timestamp', 'sender', 'message'])
    df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp, format='%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')

    # remove events not associated with a sender
    df = df[df.sender != ''].reset_index(drop=True)

    return df

df = parse_file(FULL_PATH)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same problem. It looks like whatsapp extract format different - at least for me it is now something like:

[dd/mm/yy, hh:mm:ss:] Sender: Message